# Unable to start the service

Tags: android, android-intent

I am trying to start a service

```
Intent gattServiceIntent = new Intent(this, BluetoothLeService.class);
        bindService(gattServiceIntent, mServiceConnection, BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
        startActivity(gattServiceIntent);
```

However I am getting the following message

```
07-14 20:58:13.296: E/AndroidRuntime(21311): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.rcfun.blecar/com.rcfun.blecar.util.BluetoothLeService}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
```

I tried to declare as follow

```
    <service
        android:name=".BluetoothLeService"
        android:enabled="true">            
    </service>
```

and

```
    <service
        android:name="com.rcfun.blecar.util.BluetoothLeService"
        android:enabled="true">            
    </service>
```

But both declaration gives the same error as I mentioned above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `startActivity(gattServiceIntent);` with `startService(gattServiceIntent);`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

bindService(new Intent(this,BluetoothLeService.class),mServiceConnection,Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);